# How is the " wp_get_update_data " function used?

Tags: plugins, rss

i need to list user **updates** from a word press powered site, like how we get list of comments and posts using `wp.getComments` and `wp.getPosts`, and i came across `wp_get_update_data` can we list user updates using this wp_get_update_data, and is there any chance to list updates using **rss**?

Comment: What do you mean by user updates?

Comment: its like comments and posts, normal user and admin user both can post

Comment: For that functionality I would recommend checking BuddyPress core files, they do activity stream per user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wp_get_update_data()` collects and returns number of updates available for plugins, themes and WordPress core. It's used in Admin Bar and admin update menus.