# Displaying the number of updates available in the Admin area

Tags: functions, wp-admin, admin-menu

I am having an issue finding out how to display the number of plugins/updates available to call somewhere else other than the admin header. I found the function `wp_get_update_data` should be what I need:

[How is the " wp_get_update_data " function used?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/62216/how-is-the-wp-get-update-data-function-used)

However, I wasn't sure how to get this to display as an actual count of the total plugins and updates available or any working example on the internet of how to use it.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's an example of the data returned from the `wp_get_update_data()` function:

```
Array
(
    [counts] => Array
        (
            [plugins] => 3
            [themes] => 2
            [wordpress] => 0
            [translations] => 0
            [total] => 5
        )

    [title] => 3 Plugin Updates, 2 Theme Updates
)
```

So the number of available plugin updates should be available with:

```
// Number of available plugin updates:
$update_data = wp_get_update_data();
echo $update_data['counts']['plugins'];
```

**Update:**

To display the following plugin info in the admin area:

> There are available updates for **3** plugins out of **22**

we can additionally use the [`get_plugins()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_plugins) function:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'get_plugins' ) )
{
    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php';
}

$data = array( 
    'updates'   =>  $update_data['counts']['plugins'],
    'total'     =>  count( get_plugins() ),
);

printf( 
    "There are available updates for <strong>%d</strong> plugins  
     out of <strong>%d</strong>",
    $data['updates'],
    $data['total']
);
```

We can add more info, in a similar way, with `get_mu_plugins()` and `get_dropins()`.

Comment: Sorry, but I had to undelete your answer. It adds slightly different information and clearly has its value. I hope you understand that.

Comment: @kaiser if you say so ;-) I updated the answer to make it a little bit different from the other one.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you for taking the time to explain in more detail!

Answer (score 6):

[wp_get_update_data()](http://wpseek.com/wp_get_update_data/) returns an array in this format

- counts

  - plugins
  - themes
  - wordpress
  - translations
  - total
- title

So, if you want total count, you need to use it like this

```
$updates = wp_get_update_data();
echo $updates['counts']['total'];
```

Comment: You just beat me to it by few seconds, so I will remove my answer (+1)

Comment: @birgire Great sportmanship. +1